# Call notify-send from an udev rule

Tags: udev, devices, notifications, notify-send

I use Linux Mint 13 MATE, and I'm trying to set up notifications when I plug/unplug devices.

First of all, I found [udev-notify](http://udev-notify.learnfree.eu/) package, but unfortunately it almost doesn't work for me: it works for very little time (1-2 minutes), and then, if I connect/disconnect any device, it crashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./udev-notify.py", line 319, in <module>
    notification.show()
glib.GError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.1061 was not provided by any .service files
```

I haven't found any solution, so I had to remove it. (filed [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/udev-notify/+bug/1283686) also)

Surprizingly, there're no similar utilities I've found so far. Then I tried to write udev rules that should match all devices. I have added new file `/etc/udev/rules.d/notify.rules` :

```
ACTION=="add",    RUN+="/bin/bash /home/dimon/tmp/device_plug.sh"
ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/bash /home/dimon/tmp/device_unplug.sh"
```

And two scripts:

device_plug.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=":0"
notify-send "device plugged"

/usr/bin/play -q /path/to/plug_sound.wav &
```

device_unplug.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=":0"
notify-send "device unplugged"

/usr/bin/play -q /path/to/unplug_sound.wav &
```

It works, but it works very dumb. My questions are:

1. How to get actual title of the device attached, the same as I can see in `lsusb` output? Currently, I just got notifications like "plugged" and "unpugged", and I can't find how can I retrieve the name of the device in my udev rule (If I can, then I'd pass it to my script as a parameter)
2. Currently, too many notifications are activated. Say, when I attach my USB stick, I got about 15 notifications! But, if I run `lsusb`, attached USB stick is displayed as just single device. So, it seems I should add some more argument to rule filter, but I can't find it out.
3. Probably there's some better solution for device plug/unplug notifications? Please suggest if you know something.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71432067/13480165) solution might be of help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, after many hours of googling and asking on forums, I got it working (it seems). Anyone who wants to get nice visual and/or audio notification when some USB device is plugged/unplugged can install my script, see installation details below.

First of all, answers on my own questions.

**1. How to get actual title of the device attached, the same as I can see in `lsusb` output?**

There's no such titles in the kernel (in common case). There is a database file with titles for many pairs `vendor_id:product_id`, it's usually `/usr/share/hwdata/usb.ids` file. This database can be updated by `/usr/sbin/update-usbids.sh`. Thanks to guys from [linux.org.ru](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/desktop/10220186?lastmod=1393275123956) for that info.

I don't know if there is some special tool for getting device title by pair `vendor_id:product_id`, so I had to hack a bit with `lsusb` and `grep`: for example, `lsusb | grep '0458:003a'`

**2. Currently, too many notifications are activated. Say, when I attach my USB stick, I got about 15 notifications!**

I must admit I haven't figured out how to write rule for this, but I found another way I could filter it.

`udev` allows us to use some substitutions for `RUN+="..."`: say, we can get bus number and device number by `$attr{busnum}` and `$attr{devnum}` respectively. Firstly, in my script I store list of attached devices in the special file, so that if script got new "plug" event, and this device's busnum and devnum are already stored in our file, then notification isn't generated. And secondly, these substitutions `$attr{busnum}` and `$attr{devnum}` are usually available only for one of the devices from the "series" of events. But anyway, explained algorithm should sort it out in any case.

---

Current project page: [my-udev-notify](http://goo.gl/Shbtrm).

It looks like this:

[image]

**Installation details.**

Tested on Linux Mint 13, I believe it should work on Ubuntu and other Ubuntu's derivatives, and I hope it will work on any *nix system with `udev`.

- Go to [project page](http://goo.gl/Shbtrm), get sources from there and put them somewhere. There's just one main script in it: `my-udev-notify.sh`, but archive also contains sounds for plug/unplug notifications, plus some more info, see `readme.txt` for details.
- Create file `/etc/udev/rules.d/my-udev-notify.rules` with the following contents: (don't forget to modify path to your real path where you unpacked `my-udev-notify.sh`!)

---

```
 ACTION=="add",    RUN+="/bin/bash /path/to/my-udev-notify.sh -a add    -p '%p' -b '$attr{busnum}' -d '$attr{devnum}'"
 ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/bash /path/to/my-udev-notify.sh -a remove -p '%p' -b '$attr{busnum}' -d '$attr{devnum}'"
```

---

After this, it should work for newly attached devices. That is, if you unplug
some device, you won't get notification. But when you plug it back, you will.
(yes, for me it works without any udev restarting. If it doesn't for you, try
rebooting)

To make it work for all devices, just reboot your system. NOTE that there might
be many notifications during first boot (see known issues in the `readme.txt`). On second
boot, there will be no notifications (unless you plug in new device when
system is off)

You can customize it (turn on/off visual and sound notifications, or change sounds), check readme.txt in the archive for details.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469243/how-can-i-listen-for-usb-device-inserted-events-in-linux-in-python It uses `pyudev` to get notified, and does not require extra scripts in `/etc/udev`.

Comment: Are device plug/unplug notifications hidden/unavailable by default?

Comment: @gonzobrains, no, as soon as you added correct rules to the /etc/udeve/rules.d , it should work for newly attached devices.

Comment: @DmitryFrank What I meant was are these notifications automatically shown by default or do you have to perform the above steps to show them?  For my project, I would like to suppress them (i.e., have no notifications shown by default).

Comment: @gonzobrains, if you haven't performed the steps above, and you have notifications shown when you plug/unplug any device, then my script has nothing to do with it. Some other program does this for you.

Comment: @DmitryFrank Okay, thanks.  I just want to know if default Linux installations automatically provide this or if your script/another program needs to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -u X_user DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/X_userid/bus notify-send 'Hello world!'
```

Where X_user is the user you want to run as, and X_userid is group ID of the user

example bigbird and 1000

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines before your visual notification lines, to give the script an idea about on which X display it should run the `notify-send` (or any other X application):

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority
```

Of course, you must change the second line according to your desktop environment (or display manager). This line works fine for Ubuntu 16.04 that uses unity as desktop and **lightdm** as display manager.

(from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20678530/3150964))