# How to get the list of all active X sessions and owners of them

Tags: linux, x11, session

I'm implementing USB plug/unplug notification (here's [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116536/usb-connect-disconnect-notification/116777)), and I need to execute something like `notify-send "device plugged" "My Device Title"`. The problem is that to make this command work, I should firstly set `DISPLAY`, like this:

```
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
```

And secondly, this command should be called by appropriate user. Say, for user `dimon`:

```
su dimon -c "notify-send 'device plugged' 'My Device Title'"
```

So, I need to get the list of all active X sessions and appropriate users, and call `notify-send` for each user on his `DISPLAY`.

I tried to use `w` for that, example output at Linux Mint 13 MATE:

```
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
dimon    tty8     :0               Sun15    3days  1:38m  1.95s x-session-manager
dimon    pts/0    :0               Sun15    0.00s  0.20s  0.00s tmux
```

So we have both username and display. I decided to parse it like that:

```
declare -a logged_users=(`w |grep -vP "^(USER| )" |awk '{if (NF==8){print $1" "$3} else {print $1" :0"}}' |sort |uniq`)
```

Now, I have array `logged_users`: `[0]` contains `dimon`, and `[1]` contains `:0`.  This would be great, but unfortunately it works not everywhere. Say, on Ubuntu 12.04 with lightdm we have this `w` output:

```
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
nui      tty7                      18:22   35:56   1.66s  0.11s gnome-session -
nui      pts/0    :0.0             18:55    5.00s  0.20s  0.00s w
```

No idea why there's no FROM value for `gnome-session`.
And even worse one, at xubuntu:

```
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
nui      tty7                      15:50   31:07  52.55s  0.13s /bin/sh /etc/xd
```

No display at all! If other user is logged in, no display is specified for him too (but actually it's `:1.0`)

So, I'm looking for another approach. I also know we have a list of all active X sessions here: `/tmp/.X11-unix` , and I can get the list of them like this:

```
cd /tmp/.X11-unix && for x in X*; do echo ":${x#X}"; done
```

But then, I don't know how to retrieve users.

So, how to get the list of all active X sessions and appropriate users?

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution for the users of **local** X servers (ignoring local X clients with remote or virtual X servers).

You determine the PID of the display manager (which is the parent PID of Xorg), determine the PIDs of its children and determine the user of all processes which have one of them as parent:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
xorg_pid=$(pidof -s /usr/bin/Xorg)
test -n "$xorg_pid" || exit 1
dm_pid=$(ps -eo pid,ppid,args | \
    awk -v xorg_pid=$xorg_pid '$1 == xorg_pid {print $2}')
pid_list="$(ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd | \
    awk -v dm_pid=$dm_pid '$2 == dm_pid {if (matchnr == 0) '\
'{ printf "%s%d ","$2 == ",$1; matchnr++;} '\
'else printf "%s%d ","|| $2 == ",$1;}')"
ps -eo pid,ppid,user,cmd | awk "$pid_list"'{print $3}'
```

Comment: What if you used `pgrep Xorg` instead. I have 2 running now so how would this handle multiples?

Comment: @slm You don't happen to have tried the code...?

Comment: Of course I did. I'm seeing that it only finds one.

Comment: @slm That's the intention. All instances have the same parent (at least that is the assumption of my script) thus using the first hit only is enough. I have two Xorg instances running, too. Would be difficult to test such code otherwise...

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, doesn't he want to see all the usernames that are running X?

Comment: @slm If I run this code then it gives me the user names running X.

Comment: Seems like there are issues with it, I just ran it on a CentOS system that I xrdp into and it doesn't show me or another user that are logged into it.

Comment: @slm OK, depends on how you define "X session". I understood that as "connected to a local X server".

Comment: No biggie, I was just trying to follow along, I'm curious if it works for the OP.

Comment: Hmm, the code above returns just nothing at my Linux Mint 13. I tried to verify it step-by-step, but I failed on the first one: `pidof -s /usr/bin/Xorg` returns nothing.   And, actually, I'm looking for the way that will work on (almost) all *nix systems, but people complains above that it doesn't work for them, so, it's not an option for me, unfortunately.

Comment: @DmitryFrank I guess there is no "official" way. And as long as nobody else (including yourself) is offering anything you probably should find out why this does not work on other systems (maybe the path is different or it's an upper case lower case thing) and thus help improve this suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same notify-send problem.

This method (also posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/647464/how-to-get-the-display-number-i-was-assigned-by-x?answertab=active#answer-1122517)) uses the environment information which `ps e` provides. `ps e -u username | sed -rn 's/.* DISPLAY=(:[0-9]*).*/\1/p'` outputs a list of all the DISPLAY numbers in the environments of all user *username*'s processes.

If there is a root-owned window on your desktop then root will also have some processes with the same DISPLAY number, but otherwise one DISPLAY should only be associated with one user. (Not the other way round - right now I'm logged in at two tty's with two X sessions, so I am using both :0 and :1.)

This code will output all the currently used DISPLAYs (hence all the X sessions) of all the currently logged-in users. (root is skipped)

Note the `sudo` on the `ps` command: root permissions are needed to view the environments of other users' processes. Of course if the script is run by root it's unnecessary.

Usernames and display numbers are used as the indices of associative arrays to keep only unique values.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A disps usrs
usrs=()
disps=()

for i in $(users);do
    [[ $i = root ]] && continue # skip root
    usrs[$i]=1
done # unique names

for u in "${!usrs[@]}"; do
    for i in $(sudo ps e -u "$u" | sed -rn 's/.* DISPLAY=(:[0-9]*).*/\1/p');do
        disps[$i]=$u
    done
done

for d in "${!disps[@]}";do
    echo "User: ${disps[$d]}, Display: $d"
    #sudo -u "${disps[$d]}" DISPLAY="$d" notify-send "Title" "Message"
done
```

The final commented-out line shows how notify-send could be called.