# Accessing files in USB device that's listed on lsusb command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

I'm under wsl on Windows 10 19043.1826, so I don't have the "wsl --mount" command
so i found out that I could use  **usbipd** to get the USB device 'inside' linux on wsl (Ubuntu 20.04).

then finally I get, and using command **lsusb** I got the answer:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 303a:80aa Espressif Franzininho WIFI w/Wroom
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After a long hours searching I "found the device" on /dev/bus/usb/001 folder and if I do a **ls** command on that I get the "files??" 001 and 005, as I understood (I think - wrong) my USB device is that **005**

My device (*that on Bus 001 Device 005 with ID 303a:80aa*) has a file called "code.py" on root of USB device (and device is under FAT) and I want to access this file and root folder.
How shold I do that?

I tried

```
mkdir /mnt/e
sudo mount --bind /dev/bus/usb/001/005 /mnt/e
```

but didn't work

I found a script here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634849
But didn't understood how to use that
I tried to put script on a file getdevice.sh (with nano), saved, and then tried to run

```
bash getdevice.sh 303a:80aa
```

but have nothing on response

I'm really asking here because I'm stucked literally for hours on internet seaching and trying a lot of things, and I believe this should be simple to access and I'm missing something.

with the command:

```
 lsblk -o model,name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint
```

I get only block devices I think:

```
MODEL            NAME  SIZE FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
Virtual Disk     sda   256G
Virtual Disk     sdb   256G              /
```

Comment: Try the command `lsblk -o model,name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint` and edit your original question to show the output.

Answer (score 1):

The device `/dev/bus/usb/001/005` is not for mounting - it is for sending & receiving essentially raw USB data packets, preferably using libusb or similar.

*If* the USB device is identifying itself as a standard USB storage device, then it would normally appear as some `/dev/sdX` device, where X = some letter. As suggested by sudodus, use the `lsblk` command to see if such a device is available and associated with your `Espressif Franzininho WIFI w/Wroom`.
If your USB device contains just a single filesystem with no partition table (the so-called "superfloppy" configuration), you could mount it with a command like:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/e
mount /dev/sdX /mnt/e
```

But if the device includes a partition table, and you wish to mount the first partition, you'll need to add the partition number to the device name:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/e
mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt/e
```

But the [Espressif Franzininho WIFI w/Wroom](https://www.hackster.io/fabiosouza/franzininho-wifi-board-de860d) is not a USB storage device. It's a *development board* - a tiny computer on its own, with a WiFi interface and other ways to connect things to it, so it can be used as a building block in hardware projects.

It *could* be programmed to *act* as a USB storage device, or as a multi-function device with USB storage being just one of its functions. But since it has just 4 MB of flash memory, it would be a hilariously low-capacity USB storage device unless extra flash memory chips have been added to it.

Comment: my question about accessing "as" USB storage is just to have access to the file "code.py" inside that.
Same way as I do in Windows ( I just plug, and can access as another USB storage at E: drive. If there's a way just to access this file  with command  (by VSCODE) code ./code.py is just what I need. But for that I need to reach the file location and this is what I'm trying to do, unsuccessfully.

Comment: Does it work like that on *all* Windows systems, or only on Windows that has had some special Franzininho programming drivers installed? If the latter, then the "magic" is in the Windows driver; if the former, then it might be that the default WSL kernel does not include USB-storage drivers, since Microsoft assumed Windows would be handling all the physical drive access.