# Find when new hardware is connected on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, devices, hot-plug

How can I find out when a device is connected to my FreeBSD machine? Lets say I plug in a USB device, HDMI device, Bluetooth or something like that.

Can I have a console output to say [device] and gives some output about the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All other answers are good, if you want only to check if a device is connected (checking kernel messages with `dmesg`, check in `/var/log` files and use some tools like `usbconfig`, `pciconf` or `camcontrol`).

But, if you want more (handle a message and execute a program or something like that when you plug your device), you can use [devd](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devd).

When you connect a device, FreeBSD kernel will generate messages:

- when you plug your device, an `attach` message is generated
- when you unplug your device, a `detach` message is generated
- and more (see `devd.conf` man page if you want more information).

FreeBSD uses `devd` by default, and its configuration is stored in `/etc/devd/` and `/etc/devd.conf`. If you use linux, the same features exist with `devfs` and `udev`.

You can find some examples in `/usr/share/examples/etc/devd.conf`.

Comment: this was the best, setting up devd rules allowed me to just get console logs without constantly reading the logs; thanks.

Comment: `dmesg` displays the same whether device was plugged in or not

Answer (score 5):

The `lshal` command will give you the  DMI/SMBIOS hardware information (`dmidecode` under Linux)

You can list your connected USB device through:

```
camcontrol devlist
```

Or :

```
usbconfig
```

To list `pci` devices:

```
pciconf -l
```

Also you can use the `lsusb` command under FreeBSD after Installing the `usbutils` package :

```
pkg install usbutils
```

Answer (score 2):

`dmesg | grep -i USB` will give you the list of connected

To get information about USB devices. `usbconfig` can help give it a try.

or

`pciconf -lv` pciconf diagnostic utility for the PCI bus

Comment: I am not using Mac OS

Answer (score 1):

You can output the kernel log with `dmesg`. The full log is in `/var/log/messages`. There you will find information when new devices are detected or have disappeared, and log entries about some other actions.

If you want to integrate scripts or programs, you can take a look at `/etc/devd.conf` ([man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devd.conf&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)). This is a text file containing rules with match expressions and actions. In this way you can load modules and execute binaries/scripts when devices are registered.

Answer (score 0):

You will always find info about new connected devices in dmesg and /var/log/messages.

For bluetooth you can check with: hcitool dev

For usb devices, try lsusb (-v).

Other useful commands: lshw (-short), hwinfo (--short) (if installed), lspci (-v), lsblk, df -h, fdisk -l, multipath -ll, mount, dmidecode, cat /proc/scsi/scsi, hdparm -i /dev/sda. There are multiple variations of these commands depending on your needs.

Comment: Is there a way to get console output without constantly rescanning the log messages? Isn't there some built in system so when a device is attached some type of notification is fired? I mean okay, how does the device get written to /var/log/messages. Can I intercept the call that writes the device to the log and just output it to the console instead?

Comment: You can use watch. For example:  watch "grep usb /var/log/messages | tail -20" and watch "dmesg | grep usb | tail -15". Of course you can make a script to send an email for example when a change is detected (an usb is plugged/unplugged). See this thread for more info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116536/usb-connect-disconnect-notification

Comment: @Futur'Fusionneur  First you need to install `usbutils` to be allowed to use `lsusb`.