# Executing script to affect non-root x session as root

Tags: xorg

From anther tty I can run

```
DISPLAY=:0 notify-send hullo
```

and see the message in my toothrot session.
But if I log in as root, this doesn't work.  Nor does

```
USER=toothrot DISPLAY=:0 notify-send hullo
```

How do I make it work from root?

I need this because I want to create a udev rule that affects my x session.
Using Arch.

Comment: Usually an authorization issue, see `man xauth`. But I promise you a world of pain if you try to write a udev rule that affects your X session. Don't do that, try to find a proper solution, if necessary in layers, using a dbus interface, or whatever. (What should happen if there's no X session? What if there are two or more X sessions?).

Comment: @dirkt, I don't know why that wouldn't be 'proper'?  All I want to do is update my keyboard layout when my external keyboard is attached to and removed from my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

X can have two ways of authorizing clients.
One way is using cookies; then you have to set `DISPLAY=:0` and `XAUTHORITY=/home/yourusername/.Xauthority`.

In your case I assume it is done with xhost, otherwise setting DISPLAY would not be enough. Type `xhost` to see who is authorized.

Maybe you have an `~/.Xauthority` cookie along with `xhost +SI:localuser:toothrot` authorization.

You can allow root to access display :0 with `DISPLAY=:0 xhost +SI:localuser:root`, but you have to do it as normal user. Using the cookie is the better way:

```
DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/toothrot/.Xauthority notify-send hullo
```

To execute notify-send as user:

```
su toothrot -c 'DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/toothrot/.Xauthority notify-send hullo'
```

Comment: I have the cookie, but this still doesn't work for me.

Comment: In my case, a test with xterm works. notify-send seems not work at all on my system, so I can't check if there is a difference. Does it work with xterm for you?

Comment: I don't think it depends on the emulator?  Anyway, I need it to work for a script called by a udev rule.

Comment: What I mean: Does `DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/toothrot/.Xauthority xterm` work?

Comment: Now it works with xclock (I don't have xterm). Thanks!

Comment: That's fine! You can make a try with su for notify-send: `su toothrot -c 'DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/toothrot/.Xauthority notify-send hullo'`

Comment: This works if `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`
is supplied.
`XAUTHORITY` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you solved your issue long ago, but for the sake of completion a general solution is (adapted from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571696/72707)):

```
$ my_user="toothrot"
$ my_user_id=$(more /etc/passwd | awk -F: '/^'${my_user}':/ {print $3}')
$ sudo -u $my_user DISPLAY=':0' DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/${my_user_id}/bus /usr/bin/notify-send "hullo"
```

If you have several displays of screen sessions, your mileage may vary as far as *DISPLAY=":0"* is concerned in the above. That'd be for a different post though.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are kind of crufty, and don't work cleanly for multiple users or multiple displays.  There could be a privilege escalation attack if a user symlinks `~/.Xauthority` to a protected file.  An alternative might be to forget `udev` entirely and instead use [uudev](https://github.com/stanford-scs/uudev), which runs as non-root in your own X session.  You just set up a `~/.config/uudev.conf` file that contains:

```
* ACTION="bind", DRIVER="whatever", ...
notify-send hullo
```

If you run `systemctl --user restart uudev` from within your `~/.xsession` or `~/.xinitrc` file, then `notify-send` will just get run with the appropriate `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` variables already set.